# Wrong sprite moving when touched

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I have 20 sprites in my scene which I've added to a `NSMutableArray`. My problem is that when I drag one sprite over another, the other also moves. How do I restrict the movement of untouched sprites?

Please help me with code (I am new to Cocos2d).

```
if( (self=[super init])) {

    collection=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    CCLayer *base=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Base.png"];
    base.position=ccp(512,384);
    [self addChild:base];




    x=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=7;i++)
    {
        CCSprite *hole=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ball.png"];
        hole.position=ccp(140+x,318);
        hole.tag=i;
    [self addChild:hole];
        hole.visible=YES;
        [collection addObject:hole];
        x=x+75;
    }

    self.isTouchEnabled=YES;

}
return self;
 }
 -(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
 NSLog(@"count:%i",[collection count]);
 UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
 CGPoint location=[touch locationInView:[touch view]];
 location=[[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];
 location=[self convertToNodeSpace:location];


for(CCSprite *s in collection)
{
   if(CGRectContainsPoint([s boundingBox], location))
    s.position=ccp(location.x,location.y);
    return;
 }
}
```

Comment: You have to share at least SOME code for anyone anywhere in the universe to be able to help you. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that:

Declare this in interface .h file

```
CCSprite *mSpriteOnHand;
CGPoint mLastPos;
```

Inside init assign it to nil.

```
mSpriteOnHand = nil;
```

In touchesBegan method check like this

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];


    for(CCSprite *s in collection)
    {
        if(CGRectContainsPoint([s boundingBox], location))
        {
            mLastPos = s.position;
            s.position=ccp(location.x,location.y);

            mSpriteOnHand = s;
            break;
        }
    }

}

- (void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location=[touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location=[[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];
    location=[self convertToNodeSpace:location];

    if(mSpriteOnHand)
    {
        mSpriteOnHand.position = location;
    }
}



- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if(mSpriteOnHand)
    {
         mSpriteOnHand.position = mLastPos;
         mSpriteOnHand = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: In my ccTouchesEnded method i want the sprite to back on its original position.but its not return to same position.how can i get it back to its starting point.

Comment: on touchesBegan save its touch in CGPoint mLastPos, and on touches ended reassign it to mSpriteOnHand.

Comment: I Did the same.But the position not accurate. please help me

Comment: how come it is not accurate? take backup in touchesBagan, before this line  s.position=ccp(...., then u get accurate backup. Like mLastPos = s.position, s.position = ccp(location.x,location.y);

            mSpriteOnHand = s;

Comment: updated my answer..added position restore code...happy coding...bye